# Firebase Push Notification not redirect to open facebook page and not showing app notification icon After 1 notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When I debug my application first time I am getting push notification with notification app icon and when I click on the notification it's redirect to me on my facebook page. But in second push notification m not getting notification app icon as well as not redirected to my facebook page.

Here is what I am sending through postman

```
 {
    "to": 
    "/topics/news",
  "data": {
    "extra_information": "This is some extra information"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "NEW NOTIFICATION!",
    "text": "Click me to open an Activity!",
    "click_action": "DEARACTIVITY"
  }
}
```

Here is my the My app sendNotification method

```
 private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, String click_action) {
        Intent intent;
        if(click_action.equals("DEARACTIVITY")){
            String url = "https://www.facebook.com/awwalsoft";
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
        else if(click_action.equals("MAINACTIVITY")){

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }else{
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

I want, whenever I send click_action = DearActivity then the push notification redirected to my facebook page.

Comment: So you send a notification with data, because of that the notification when app is in background the notification is processed by the system tray and not by the FirebaseMessegingService.

Comment: Try send notification only with data, if you can I can create a detailed answer.

Comment: should i removed notification details like title an all

Comment: Yes remove that and add title and texto to data and notification will be processed only by the FirebaseMessegingService.

Comment: To better help read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: after removing this m not getting notification

Comment: you need to update the code too.

Comment: inside sendnotification you need to get the data and create the notification.

Comment: can you  elaborate,

Comment: yes. I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try do that:

```
{
    "to": 
    "/topics/news",
  "data": {
    "extra_information": "This is some extra information"
    "title": "NEW NOTIFICATION!",
    "text": "Click me to open an Activity!",
    "click_action": "DEARACTIVITY"
  }
}
```

And to get the data do this inside the FirebaseMessagingService:

```
String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
String text=remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
String clickAction=remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
String extrainfo=remoteMessage.getData().get("extra_information");
```

And send strings to the notification.

And finally:

```
if(clickAction.equals("DEARACTIVITY")){
            String url = "https://www.facebook.com/awwalsoft";
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
        else if(clickAction.equals("MAINACTIVITY")){

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }else{
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
```